# Does Drupal have its own CLI?

Tags: installation

It is unclear to me from the [this document](https://www.drupal.org/project/ideas/issues/3089277) if Drupal has its own CLI, different from *Drush* and *Drupal Console* and including some very basic commands such as cache flush and installing a module.

Does Drupal have its own CLI?

- Is it a local or global CLI?
- Is it usable in XAMPP?

Comment: Don't use XAMPP. Use DDEV: Composer, PHP, SQL, everything in containers, and it's fast, much faster than XAMPP.

Comment: I second DDEV, as it comes bundled with everything you need to develop Drupal systems.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal does not currently have its own CLI that is bundled with a standard Drupal installation.

The issue that you linked to is a feature request/proposal that has not been implemented yet.  It may be implemented at some point, but reading through the issue, it is still a plan at this stage.

Drush is effectively the Drupal CLI; it has been around since at least the days of Drupal 5, and it supports most core features and also is supported by many contrib modules.

My guess is that the core feature request that you linked to hasn't moved forward because Drush already exists and does what people need.

Drush can be used with XAMPP; it can basically be used anywhere that you have either local or SSH access (which means some very cheap shared hosting providers will not allow you to use it, but it will basically work everywhere else).

Comment: Confusion maybe came from this sentence in the linked issue: "We already have Symfony console component in Drupal core (/core/scripts/drupal) and it has some commands." But we don't know where the confusion came from since OP didn't tell us what exactly made it unclear to them.

Comment: Drush is Drupal's CLI. It is extremely well developed.

Answer (score 2):

As the issue, which is not documentation but rather an idea issue, reads, there are a tiny few commands in Drupal Core, which would not be useful in most cases at this time. It is a “local” CLI if I understand you correctly and should be executable in any context.

You have not found an undocumented way to avoid Drush. I advise not to try it. Use Drush.

Answer (score 0):

> from the this document

Please take a closer look, it's not a documentation, it's "Drupal core ideas".

> Does Drupal have its own CLI?

Yes.

> Is it a local or global CLI?

Local.

> Is it usable in XAMPP?

Usable is a matter of opinion but I'd argue the answer is "no".

The available commands are:

- generate-theme  Generates a new theme based on latest default markup.
- help            Display help for a command
- install         Installs a Drupal demo site. This is not meant for production and might be too simple for custom development. It is a quick and easy way to get Drupal running.
- list            List commands
- quick-start     Installs a Drupal site and runs a web server. This is not meant for production and might be too simple for custom development. It is a quick and easy way to get Drupal running.
- server          Starts up a webserver for a site.

Since XAMPP is already a webserver and it's unlikely you are developing a custom theme at this point, I would argue this is not at all useful to you. Indeed use drush.